# OpenAPI generic data

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Is it possible to describe generic response which includes other fields and list of generic type objects in OpenAPI 3.
How it simplified looks from class perspective:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> data;
    private int field1;
    private int field2;
    ...
}
```

```
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: MyClass
                  - type: object
                    properties:
                      data:
                        type: array
                        items:
                          type: AnotherEntityClassForGeneric
```

What I have tried to use is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499445/openapi-3-0-generic-data-types).

Initially found it as perfect answer for my situation, but still it doesn't work for me.

So, what I should try to do or is it even possible in OpenAPI 3.0 using YAML configuration file?